# I lost my octopress local folder and can't find `source` branch in my github page , How do i continue blogging?

Tags: git, github, jekyll, octopress

Unfortunately i deleted the octopress folder .
I had deployed my website here : https://github.com/yask123/yask123.github.io.git

This repo doesn't contain source branch , how do i continue blogging ?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Did you still have sources on you local machine ?

Comment: Nopes! I guess there isn't any way. https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/1719
I am doomed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can recover all your `source/` content. I was able to navigate to your repo, select source branch, and see all your markdown files.
In your terminal:

```
cd where/you/have/your/projectName
mkdir projectName
git clone https://github.com/yask123/yask123.github.io.git
git checkout source
```

Now you have a local copy and you can work in your blog as usual.